# Why is my string not match()ing?

Tags: java, regex

I have a multiline XML blob in a Java String that I'd like to grep some values out of.  I know that regexes and XML mix like crude oil and pasta, but I promise that I'm really not trying anything complicated.

Sample XML `object` String:

```
<ObjectDto>
  <created>1313825589244</created>
  <description>description</description>
  <id>649</id>
  <isFoo>true</isFoo>
<ObjectDto>
```

All I want is for `object.matches("<isFoo>true</isFoo>")` to evaluate to `true`.  I've tried wrapping the meat of the regex in `.*` (and `[\n.]*` in case the newlines were throwing it), but no joy.

**Why doesn't it match?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't matching newlines hard enough, turning on DOTALL `(?s).*<isFoo>true</isFoo>.*` fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Because you haven't read the documentation.

> Attempts to match the **entire** input sequence against the pattern.
>
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the
>   start, end, and group methods.

You should either add a non-greedy dot operator at the start and end or just use the `find()` method.

Comment: And as I mentioned you should use the non-greedy version.

Comment: Because otherwise .* matches the complete input and match finds that there's still some part of the RE left that wasn't matched -> ergo no match, though I always forget the details about the java RE lib.

Comment: I won't argue that regexes are a good tool for this task, but I'm not sure about your explanation of them.  Using `(?s).*<isFoo>true</isFoo>.*` (note extra greedy `.`) works fine.

Comment: Yeah you're right - the problem is the dozens of different RE libraries. Java a) doesn't use possessive operators by default (good idea that) and b) as you found out yourself doesn't match the newline by default (that's annoying imo, but certainly perl's fault)